# Django flatpages template tag doesn't work with template inheritance

Tags: python, django, django-1.6, django-flatpages

I have a Django (1.6) application that inherits a base template. I would like to include one of my (currently working) flatpages into the application landing page, something that the [Django docs say is possible](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/flatpages/#getting-a-list-of-flatpage-objects-in-your-templates).

Here is my template:

```
{% extends "path/to/base.html" %}
{% load flatpages %}
{% get_flatpages as fp %}

{% block content %}
  <h3>Flatpage inclusion</h3>
  <p>Number of flatpages: {{ fp|length }}
  <ul>
    {% for page in fp %}
      <li><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}       
  </ul> 
{% endblock content %}
```

This does not list any of the flatpages. However, if I remove the `{% extends %}` signal, so my code looks like this:

```
{% load flatpages %}
{% get_flatpages as fp %}

<h3>Flatpage inclusion</h3>
<p>Number of flatpages: {{ fp|length }}
<ul>
  {% for page in fp %}
    <li><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}       
</ul>
```

Everything works. I see the number of flatpages in my `fp` object (9) and my unordered list shows all the flatpage urls and titles.

This seems to me to be a bug in either how flatpages work, or how Django does template inheritance.

The base template (`/path/to/base.html`) doesn't have anything complex in it.

[Django categorically says that this is possible](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#custom-libraries-and-template-inheritance):

> When you load a custom tag or filter library, the tags/filters are only made available 
>   to the current template – not any parent or child templates along the template-inheritance path.
>
> For example, if a template foo.html has {% load humanize %}, a child template (e.g., one that 
>   has {% extends "foo.html" %}) will not have access to the humanize template tags and filters. 
>   The child template is responsible for its own {% load humanize %}.
>
> This is a feature for the sake of maintainability and sanity.

Has anyone else noticed this bug? Is it an exception for just the built-in flatpages app?

**EDIT 1:**

Daniels answer is correct. The [example code from the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/flatpages/#getting-a-list-of-flatpage-objects-in-your-templates) doesn't show including flatpage content within a `{% block %}`, so I didn't expect that it needed to be done:

```
{% load flatpages %}
{% get_flatpages as flatpages %}
<ul>
  {% for page in flatpages %}
    <li><a href="{{ page.url }}">{{ page.title }}</a></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

My fault I guess. Live and learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `get_flatpages` tag is outside any blocks from the parent template. That means it simply won't be called.

Move it into the content block and it should work.

Comment: Hi Daniel - Thanks! This worked. Odd that the Django documentation doesn't explicitly say this, or maybe I am just being dense....

Answer (score 0):

Just to reiterate the correct solution- `get_flatpages` needs to be placed **inside** the block where it's going to be referenced. So this will work:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% load flatpages %}

{% block footer %}
    {% get_flatpages as flatpages %}
    {% for page in flatpages %}
    ...
    {% endfor %}
```

And this **will not** work:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% load flatpages %}
{% get_flatpages as flatpages %}

{% block footer %}        
    {% for page in flatpages %}
    ...
    {% endfor %}
```

And yes, Django documentation isn't very clear on that.